# A problem occurred evaluating project ':nordic_nrf_mesh'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, bluetooth, mesh

I have a problem that when I run the application on flutter, it gives me this error in the terminal

what i want to do is to scan the nearest bluetooth device, get the uuid and node from that device then control it example: control light

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Where:
Build file 'C:%user%\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\nordic_nrf_mesh-0.12.0\android\build.gradle' line: 44
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':nordic_nrf_mesh'.
Project with path ':mesh' could not be found in project ':nordic_nrf_mesh'.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

the line 44 was come from the nordic_nrf_mesh library in my C:%user%\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\nordic_nrf_mesh-0.12.0\android\build.gradle

i don't know how to fix it

all i want to do is use the nordicNrfMesh.scanForUnprovisionedNodes

here is my function to scan

```
 Future<void> _scanUnprovisionned() async {
    _serviceData.clear();
    setState(() {
      _devices.clear();
    });
    widget.nordicNrfMesh.scanForUnprovisionedNodes().listen((event) {});
    _scanSubscription =
        widget.nordicNrfMesh.scanForUnprovisionedNodes().listen((device) async {
      if (_devices.every((d) => d.id != device.id)) {
        final deviceUuid = Uuid.parse(
            getDeviceUuid(device.serviceData[meshProvisioningUuid]!.toList()));
        debugPrint('deviceUuid: $deviceUuid');
        debugPrint('deviceName: ${device.name}');
        debugPrint('deviceDeviceId: ${device.id}');
        debugPrint('deviceManfac: ${device.manufacturerData.toString()}');
        debugPrint('deviceRssi: ${device.rssi.toString()}');
        _serviceData[device.id] = deviceUuid;
        _devices.add(device);
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
    setState(() {
      isScanning = true;
    });
    return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10)).then((_) => _stopScan());
  }
```

here is my build.gralde

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.dienquang.flutter_nrfmesh_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
```

i also add the Android-nRF-Mesh-Library file to my flutter

Pls help me

Comment: You might get a faster (or better) answer when opening an issue at https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-nRF-Mesh-Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:
i open an issue on github and got the awswer now it work fine for me

https://github.com/OZEO-DOOZ/nrf_mesh_plugin/issues/249

did should to the trick for anyone stuck it this error